# Web scraping (Request -> JsDom -> Cheerio) not working with SPA (client side scripts)

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio, jsdom

Trying to scrape a site that has scripts that run after page load but JsDom doesn't seem to do this, I can get this working with zombie.js (which uses jsDom under the hood). I would like to not use zombie js, as I don't need all the testing framework stuff.

This is jsDom code:

```
const request = require('request');
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const domain = 'https://www.google.co.uk'
const usa = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36';

module.exports = function(cb) {
  const url = `${domain}/#q=monkeys`;
   request({ uri: url, headers: { 'User-Agent': usa } }, function (err, res, body) {
      if (err && res.statusCode !== 200) throw err;
      const window = jsdom.jsdom(body, { 
        url: url,
        userAgent: usa,
        features: {
          FetchExternalResources: ['script'],
          ProcessExternalResources: ['script']
        }
      }).defaultView;
      window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        // console.log(window.document.body.innerHTML)
        // This HTML has scripts.
        let $ = cheerio.load(window.document);
        let els = $('SELECTOR').map(function () {
          // Other code
        }).get();    
        cb(url, els);
        window.close();   
     });
  });
}
```

This the zombie js code which works:

```
const Browser = require('zombie');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const domain = 'https://www.google.co.uk'
const usa = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36';

module.exports = function(cb) {
  const url = `${domain}/#q=monkeys`;
  const browser = new Browser({userAgent: usa});
  browser.visit(url, () => {
    browser.wait(window => window.document.getElementById('rhs'), function() {
      let $ = cheerio.load(browser.html());
      let els = $('SELECTOR').map(function () {
        // Other code
      }).get();
      cb(url, els)
      browser.window.close();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: "that has scripts that run after page load but" - JSDOM is pure javascript parser, it does not have the browser functionality to execute the code. If you need this functionality you should look for headless browser Phantomjs and its higher lever wrapper CasperJS.

Comment: Also the same applies to Cheerio which only does the HTML parsing.

Comment: ^ This. Nightmare may be a good solution for Node in this case.

Comment: Yes the jsdom does execute the script included to page, but you need to be sure that the code is loaded, use some external loader example https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#custom-external-resource-loader

Comment: Yes I'm aware out of the box it doesn't, trying to get resource loader to work. I have tried nightmare but that spins up a new electron each scrape which could be very intensive. I was seeing if i could get jsdom working as that would be most efficient.